# Strange git behavior, including git status error after adding directory

Tags: git, github, gedit

Stackoveflow.  I'm a noob...so be gentle.

**Question #1:** After a new install, did a commit for README file no problem.  Made changes to README with a text editor, made a new commit, and *nada*...the changes did not show in GitHub's online repository.  I've checked all necessary keys, etc. **Had to do "git push" to make local working directory changes appear in online repository...at which point, yes, committed changes are then visible in GitHub.  Is that normal?**

**Question #2:** re-posted here...

[Adding a Directory to be Tracked in Git; Error Message; Size Limit for Adds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728774/adding-a-directory-to-be-tracked-in-git-error-message-size-limit-for-adds)

**Question #3:** re-posted here...

[Gedit with Git in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740700/gedit-with-git-in-windows)

Comment: You should create 3 separate questions instead a big one like this

Comment: I mean, (for example) people might know #1 and #2 but not #3 and won't submit an incomplete answer

Comment: I googled #3 for you: http://eddieringle.com/how-to-properly-configure-git-to-use-gedit-as-its-default-editor/ :)

Comment: @Pablo Fernandez: thanks...will make sure I do that next time around.  @Simon: thanks...saw that post myself, and tried it...to no avail.

Comment: @Sean: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't wait until next time, you can edit your question *now*. Remove #2 and #3 from here, and create two new questions. They are good enough to stand on their own.

Comment: @Pablo and @Greg: okay! Per your suggestion, I've re-posted two parts of my tripartite question separately.  :-)  (@Greg... I just discovered the edit button.  Doh!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer #1: Yes, that's normal. Creating a commit only affects your local repository. You need to push or pull commits to move them between repositories. It's not like subversion :)

Answers #2 and #3: No idea. Sorry.

Hopefully at least #1 is cleared up for you.

@Pablo might be right: try creating new questions for 2 and 3, as they are pretty much unrelated.

Comment: thanks...re. #1. That makes me rest a little easier.  Thought I was doing something incorrectly.