# Gedit with Git in Windows?

Tags: git, gedit

Is there *any way* to use Gedit as the core.editor for Git in Windows?

Comment: You don't have to give a reasoning for why you like GEdit / support GEdit...

Comment: Since this doesn't seem related to Vim, I've removed the `vim` tag.

Comment: I've removed your reasonings, and left the simple question. You'll have more luck getting an answer that way.

Comment: Do you have gedit installed in your windows machine?

Comment: @manojlds, @greg, @citizen conn...y'all are right: smarter to keep it succint.  Thanks.  Just wanted to make it clear I had scoured the other Gedit in Git posts in SO.  @yasouser: yes...I have Gedit installed in a dual boot machine.  I'm increasingly working in Windows vs. Ubuntu, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your gedit bin directory to environment variable %PATH%, then configure git core.editor "gedit"

Comment: can you be a li'l more detailed in your response?  I found this on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550490/how-can-i-put-home-opt-git-bin-to-my-path  Still a bit confused.  Should the %PATH% for Git begin from a high enough directory (e.g., Prog Files (x86) / Git / ..  that it contains BOTH the git AND the gedit executables?  Or just randomly insert directory of Gedit's executable anywhere in path?  AND: the change must be done via Git console, yes? (...and not via direct edit of a file in a Git directory...like using an editor to adjust the git-config file?)

Comment: Just add the path that contains gedit executables to %PATH%, you can do this via System Properties (right clicking My Computer, Adv. sys. settings) > Env. Variables > Sys. Variables, Path, edit > add e.g., ";C:\Opt\Gedit\bin"
Finally, `configure git core.editor "gedit"` on your Git console. You can even run gedit by typing "gedit" directly on the console.

Answer (score 3):

Though this question doesn't answer your question directly, it does talk about setting up an editor to work with Git for Windows: [How can I set up an editor to work with Git on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564/how-can-i-set-up-an-editor-to-work-with-git-on-windows)

This question might also be useful for you incase you run into problems while changing the default editor: [Unable to change the default editor in terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647032/unable-to-change-the-default-editor-in-terminal)